# Any way to screenshot through ADB on Windows Subsystem for Android?

Tags: windows, adb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, subsystem

I tried `adb exec-out screencap -p > "screenshot.png"`, but it returned a 800x1280 white image as the PNG output. Any idea on how to screenshot directly through Windows Subsystem for Android's ADB?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.